# manipulate a pair data in R

Tags: r, reshape

I would like to reshape the data sample below, so that to get the output like in the table. How can I reach to that? the idea is to split the column `e` into two columns according to the disease. Those with disease 0 in one column and those with disease 1 in the other column. thanks in advance.

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), fid = c(1, 
1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5), disease = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
1), e = c(3, 2, 6, 1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 1, 1)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
 pivot_wider(fid, names_from = disease, values_from = e, names_prefix = 'e') %>%
 select(-fid)
     e0    e1
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     3     2
2     6     1
3     5     2
4     3     2
5     1     1
```

if you want the `e1,e2` you could do:

```
df %>%
 pivot_wider(fid, names_from = disease, values_from = e,
                  names_glue = 'e{disease + 1}') %>%
 select(-fid)
# A tibble: 5 x 2
     e1    e2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     3     2
2     6     1
3     5     2
4     3     2
5     1     1
```

Comment: is this can work for doing some in multiple columns?

Comment: @Lisa yes try it out

Answer (score 0):

We could use `lead()` combined with `ìfelse` statements for this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(e2 = lead(e)) %>% 
  filter(row_number() %% 2 == 1) %>% 
  mutate(e1 = ifelse(disease==1, e2,e),
         e2 = ifelse(disease==0, e2,e)) %>% 
  select(e1, e2)
```

```
    e1    e2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     3     2
2     6     1
3     5     2
4     3     2
5     1     1
```